# Add custom space to UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, uilabel

I've a weird problem that faces me. I've a UILabel contains text of multiple lines and I'm using bullet in the first line "•".
But my problem is that the second line is not aligned with first character after the bullet. 
I measured it and found that width of the bullet is a little bit bigger tan width of normal space.
Is there any trick for that?

Comment: You could make the bullet be a different UILabel, and the text be a left-justified one. A bit kludgy, but it will work.

Comment: Okay, I found a powerful answer by using NSParagraphStyle. https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2016/04/10/bullet-point-list-ios-swift/

Answer (score 0):

the issue is concerning font attributes. Get into the difference of monospaced fonts and proportional fonts, then you will know why there's a difference between space and bullet in your font

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

easy solution and maybe really an option for you is to use a monospaced font.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a powerful answer by using NSParagraphStyle.
https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2016/04/10/bullet-point-list-ios-swift/

Comment: This isn't an answer but more of a comment. Please update your "answer" with relevant code so it helps future readers.